# Scala: Parse JSON into a case class with overriding with annotate JsonGetter

Tags: json, scala, jackson, annotations

I have a JSON I'm constructing using scala Jackson object mapper passing it to the case class

```
    case class RequestJson( @(JsonGetter @field)("app_token")token:String,
                                            id: String,)  {
require(StringUtils.isNotBlank(id), "id argument cannot be blank")
    }
```

I was expecting JsonGetter should replace the "`token`" with `app_token`
and resultant JSON to be

```
{
  "app_token" : "myToken",
  "id" : "123"
}
```

but I get

```
{
      "token" : "myToken",
      "id" : "123"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work with register DefaultScalaModule and FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES as false.

Case Class code snippet:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter
import scala.annotation.meta.field

case class RequestJson(@(JsonGetter @field)("app_token") token: String, id: String) {}
```

Mapper code snippet:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)

val request = RequestJson("mytoken", "123")
val str = mapper.writeValueAsString(request)
println(str)
//{"app_token":"mytoken","id":"123"}
```